# SonarQube 5.6.1 throwing bad major version while compiling a Java 7 project with Ant

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube, sonarqube5.6

I have a Jenkins job that uses Ant to build a project.

The project is in Java 7. The runtime for the Jenkins job is also Java 7. I'm using SonarQube 5.6.1 which runs on Java 8. SonarQube server is running fine.

However, when it's time to invoke the `<sonar:sonar />` target in Ant, I get the following error which clearly is due to a Java version mismatch (`JVMCFRE003 bad major version`). I am not sure how to solve this.

```
sonar:
parsing buildfile jar:file:/opt/Ant_1.9.7/lib/sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar!/org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/opt/Ant_1.9.7/lib/sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar!/org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
parsing buildfile jar:file:/opt/Ant_1.9.7/lib/sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar!/org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/opt/Ant_1.9.7/lib/sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar!/org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
[available] Found: /var/lib/jenkins/slave/workspace/Build/Component/Build-subcomponent/builds/com.mycompany.myproj.bootstrap.site/compile
parsing buildfile jar:file:/opt/Ant_1.9.7/lib/sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar!/org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/opt/Ant_1.9.7/lib/sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar!/org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
[sonar:sonar] Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.7 compiled on April 9 2016
[sonar:sonar] SonarQube Ant Task version: 2.2
[sonar:sonar] Loaded from: file:/opt/Ant_1.9.7/lib/sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
[sonar:sonar] INFO: Work directory: /var/lib/jenkins/slave/workspace/Build/Component/Build-subcomponent/com.mycompany.myproj.bootstrap.site/../builds/com.mycompany.myproj.bootstrap.site/sonar
[sonar:sonar] INFO: SonarQube Server 5.6.1

BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/slave/workspace/Build/Component/Build-subcomponent/build/common.xml:229: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/sonar/api/utils/SonarException, offset=6
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:324)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:712)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:492)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:595)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedClassloader.loadClass(IsolatedClassloader.java:94)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:731)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:94)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:514)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1116)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:85)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:53)
    at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:48)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:155)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:854)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that we're talking about a Jenkins job, and the version of Java used for the job will be used for each step in the job. Since you're running the job with Java 7, the analysis is also running with Java 7 & that's not compatible with SonarQube 5.6+.

The easiest thing to do is move analysis from the Ant script into a SonarQube Scanner Build Step; it will let you choose a different Java version from the one running the job.

Alternately you could maybe accomplish this [with a pipeline](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204421664-Select-which-Java-JDK-to-use-in-Pipeline)

```
node() {
  def jdk8 = tool 'jdk-8u45'
  def jdk7 = tool 'jdk-7u70'
  withEnv(["PATH+JDK7=${jdk7}/bin"]) {
    sh 'ant [normal target here]'
  }
  withEnv(["PATH+JDK8=${jdk8}/bin"]) {
    sh 'ant [analysis target here]'
  }
}
```

Your third option would be to split the job in 2 and use a shared workspace (*Configure > Project Options > Advanced > Use custom workspace*)

Comment: Hi G. Ann. I'm not sure I understand - where is the mismatch here? Why does the Ant plug-in depend on the version of the SonarQube server?

Comment: In other words, why can't `sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar` be Java 7, analyze Java 7 code, then upload the analysis results to SonarQube server running on Java 8? it doesn't make sense to me. The requirements page of SQ 5.6.1 says "The SonarQube Java analyser is able to analyse any kind of Java source files regardless of the version of Java they comply to"